# Hide EXPORT option in more button in OPENERP 7

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

How to hide the EXPORT Option in the more button for specific user group, and how to hide the 'MORE' button for specific user group in openerp 7.

Answer (score 0):

Hide "Export in More Option"

in OpenERP-7

Create XML File Under **static/src/base.xml** in your module and add this code:

```
<templates>
        <t t-extend="Sidebar">
            <t t-jquery="a.oe_sidebar_action_a" t-operation="replace">
                <t t-if="widget.session.uid !== 1">
                <a t-if="item.label !== 'Export'" class="oe_sidebar_action_a" t-att-title="item.title or ''" t-att-data-section="section.name" t-att-data-index="item_index" t-att-href="item.url" target="_blank">
                     <t t-raw="item.label"/>
                 </a>
                </t>
                <t t-if="widget.session.uid === 1">
                    <a class="oe_sidebar_action_a" t-att-title="item.title or ''" t-att-data-section="section.name" t-att-data-index="item_index" t-att-href="item.url" target="_blank">
                         <t t-raw="item.label"/>
                    </a>
                </t>
            </t>
        </t>
</templates>
```

Add this in File **__openerp__.py**:

```
'qweb': [ 
    "static/src/base.xml", 
]
```

Now restart the server and update your database and refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it will hide the EXPORT option to the entire group, but I have to hide for  particular Group